# No WiFi adapter found - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Dell E7440

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I have made several attempts to configure WiFi on my Ubuntu. However, I have not been able to succeed so far. I have a Dell E7440 laptop and I have my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS configured on Oracle VM.

I have tried several proposed solutions to reinstall, update software but none of those have worked.

Any help to resolve this will be appreciated.

Solutions tried so far:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dokG4bCF4GQ
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8o0XYfRn5sc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxB6asfgKOc

```
    lshw -C network

     *-network                 
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 3
           bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
           logical name: enp0s3
           version: 02
           serial: 08:00:27:02:03:5f
           size: 1Gbit/s
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 32 bits
           clock: 66MHz
           capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.178.206 latency=64 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
           resources: irq:19 memory:f8200000-f821ffff ioport:d020(size=8)
```

Comment: You can't configure wireless on a VM. VM's use network connections from the host system.

Comment: Does this solve your problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/379438/how-do-i-connect-to-the-wifi-in-ubuntu-within-my-virtual-machine

Comment: @Idias - moreover, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/379454/212930) further illustrates this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several solutions yesterday.

I obtained this answer from DELL support:
https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/es-es/000193252/wi-fi-6e-not-supported-on-client-linux-operating-system?lwp=rt

MY SOLUTION:

- Update DELL BIOS
- Change Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS for Ubuntu 21.10 (non LTS)

Comment: I do not see how changing the OS is a fix for the question as asked.

Comment: @David The latest version of Ubuntu has better support for new devices.